# a c++ function that enables input editing in a data structure

Tags: c++, struct

I am designing a Logic Gate data structure in C++ called AND that has 3 functions:

a function that takes input either 1 or 0 from the user.
a function that shows output of AND Gate from the input.
a function that asks user if they want to edit their inputs and if yes, then allows them to edit the inputs they have entered.
Problem is that I cannot figure out how to call the function that edits input in the main. Following is my code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct AND  //structure called AND
{
   int x, y;

   AND()    //constructor
   {
      x, y = 0;             //declaring variables as inputs
   }

   void inputAND()      //function that takes inputs from the user
   {
      cin >> x;
      cin >> y;
   }

   void outputAND()                       //function that displays output
   {
      if (x == 0 || y == 0)
      {
         cout << "0" << endl;
      }

      else if (x == 1 && y == 1)
      {
         cout << "1" << endl;
      }
   }

   void changeInputAND(AND change[])       //function for changing inputs
   {
      cout << "Do you wish change first input Yes/No:" << endl;       
      string t;
      cin >> t;
      int k;
      if (t == "Yes" || "yes")
      {

         cout << "Enter New Input ";

         cin >> k;
         x = k;

      }
      else
      {
         k = x;
      }

      cout << "Do you wish to change the second input Yes/No:" << endl;
      {
         string s;
         cin >> s;
         int l;
         if (t == "Yes" || "yes")
         {
            cout << "enter new input";
            cin >> l;
            y = l;
         }
      }
   }
};

void main()
{
   AND a1;
   a1.input();   //calling the input function
   a1.output();  //calling the output function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for improvement and how to implement the task of editing an `AND` object.

1. Keep your class as simple as you can. Don't pollute it with code related input and output streams.

   ```
   struct AND  //structure called AND
   {
      int x, y;

      AND() : x(0), y(0)   //constructor
      {
      }

      void setX(int newX)
      {
         x = newX;
      }

      void setY(int newY)
      {
         y = newY;
      }
   };
   ```
2. Initialize members of a `class` in the initializer list instead of assigning to them in the body of a constructor.

   Prefer to use:

   ```
   AND() : x(0), y(0)   //constructor
   {
   }
   ```

   over

   ```
   AND()    //constructor
   {
      x = y = 0;
   }
   ```
3. Move the code to read and write from member functions to non-member functions. Don't assume whether the input/output streams are `std::cin` or `std::cout`. The driver code can choose to use `std::cin`/`std::cout` or it may choose a file, `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream`.

   ```
   // Write data to a stream
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, AND const& a)
   {
      return out << a.x << " " << a.y;
   }

   // Read data from a stream
   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, AND& a)
   {
      in >> a.x >> a.y;
   }
   ```

   Also, it's better to make sure that write/read are such that what is written out can be read back.
4. Create a non-member function for reading user data and changing the object instead of putting it all in a member function.

   ```
   // Non-member function for changing the object.
   void changeInputAND(AND& a)
   {
      cout << "Do you wish change first input Yes/No:" << endl;       

      string ans;
      cin >> ans;

      if (ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes")
      {
         cout << "Enter New Input ";

         int x;
         cin >> x;
         a.setX(x);
      }

      cout << "Do you wish to change the second input Yes/No:" << endl;

      cin >> ans;
      if (ans == "Yes" || ans == "yes")
      {
         cout << "enter new input";
         int y;
         cin >> y;
         a.setY(y);
      }
   }
   ```

   BTW, your attempt at comparing with `"Yes"` or `"yes"` is flawed.

   ```
      if (ans == "Yes" || "yes")
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```
      if ( (ans == "Yes") || "yes")
   ```

   That will always evaluate to `true`. That's a very different topic :)
5. Put it all together in one or more functions to test the `AND` functionality, preferably different from `main`.

   ```
   void testAND()
   {
      AND a1;
      std::cin >> a1;                // calling the input function
      std::cout << a1 << std::endl;  // calling the output function
      changeInputAND(a1);            // function for changing inputs

      std::cout << a1 << std::endl;  // calling the output function again
   }
   ```
6. Call the test function from `main`.

   ```
   void main()
   {
      testAND();
      return 0;
   }
   ```